# Ubuntu gnome clipboard

Tags: ubuntu, clipboard

How do I set up Ubuntu so that when I highlight text in a terminal it automatically goes to the clipboard and when I right click it pastes ?

Answer (score 1):

Do you really want it to go to the clipboard?  Right now, I suspect a middle-click will paste your current selection into the place you middle-click on.

[JWZ's explanation](http://www.jwz.org/doc/x-cut-and-paste.html) is pretty much the most readable one I've ever run across.  Highly recommended.